# List Item Edit Form/View: show a table/border

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-item, edit-form

So if I click on a item of a list, the item will open and I can see further information of it.

In this view, I'd like to paint a border around the information and seperate every information.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

As this is a webpart, I assume - or hope - I can do some magic with JSLink property or something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can script it with JavaScript and **connect** that file with a JSLink reference.
That's basically the same concept as whacking a jQuery script and a Conten/Script Editor WebPart in the Page

Or you can apply CSS

CSS is easier, better maintainable, but you need good CSS skills

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Have to check that deeply. My CSS skills are below zero. But thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you want to bake a cake but don't know the difference between flour and salt, you have some learning to do